# JS Fetch takes only OPTIONS request and print that out

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch-api

Im trying to make a request from my React App to my backend server, the frontend do a OPTIONS request and that is OK, the problem is that my then on the fetch console logs the OPTIONS response, and not the real response that is made efter the OPTIONS request.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/kp/ticket', {
        headers: {
            "token": sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        },
        mode: 'cors',
        method: 'GET'
}).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Even if you say the proposed answer works for you, I still think it is a workaround rather than a fix for the underlying problem. Pre-flight requests are supposed to be handled transparently by the browser, you should not get “in contact” with that in your code at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/kp/ticket', {
        headers: {
            "token": sessionStorage.getItem('token')
        },
        mode: 'cors',
        method: 'GET'
}).then(data => (data.json())
.then(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in "Other" tab in chrome devtools. Not in XHR